# Slider jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement basic sliding functionality using jQuery, pls find the code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard-crousel" id="spanCarousel">
     <span>My Order</span>
     <span class="selected">Recommendations</span>
     <span>My Profile</span>
     <div id="controls">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dashboard-crouselLeftArrow"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dashboard-crouselRightArrow"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var slider = {
    length: parseInt($("#spanCarousel").children("span").length),
    current: 1,
    width: $("#spanCarousel").width(),
    next: function(){
        if(this.current < this.length){
            this.current = this.current + 1;
            this.animation();
        } else {
            this.current = 1;
            this.animation();
        }
    },
    animation: function(){ 
        var target = (0 - this.width) * (this.current - 1);
        this.run("#spanCarousel", target);

    },
    prev: function(){

        if(this.current > 1){
            this.current = this.current - 1;
            this.animation();
        } else {
            this.current = this.length;
            this.animation();
        }
    },
    run: function(part, target){
        $(part + " .pan").stop().animate(
            {"margin-left": target},
            1000
        );
    },
    initialize: function(){
        $("#controls .dashboard-crouselLeftArrow").click(function(){slider.next();});
        $("#controls .dashboard-crouselRightArrow").click(function(){slider.prev();});
    }
}

slider.initialize();  
</script>
```

[image]

I just want to slide content between the arrows as shown in the image.

I want to move text left to right endless. pls help

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistake in your code. But since i do not have your css i could not make you a working exemple and try out.

The function `parseInt` is taking [two parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), string and radix. However you are never putting the second parameter.

Secondly a semi colon is missing at the very end of your programm.

```
  initialize: function(){
    $("#controls .dashboard-crouselLeftArrow").click(function(){slider.next();});
    $("#controls .dashboard-crouselRightArrow").click(function(){slider.prev();});
}};
```

you might use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to debbug your future code, it is a really effective tool.